# Kubernetes https ingress 400 response

Tags: https, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a bare-metal kubernetes cluster (1.13) and am running nginx ingress controller (deployed via helm into the default namespace, v0.22.0).

I have an ingress in a different namespace that attempts to use the nginx controller.

```
#ingress.yaml
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: myapp
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: https
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-rewrite-log: "true"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my-host
    secretName: tls-cert
  rules:
  - host: my-host
    paths:
    - backend:
        servicename: my-service
        servicePort: https
      path: "/api/(.*)"
```

The nginx controller successfully finds the ingress, and says that there are endpoints. If I hit the endpoint, I get a 400, with no content. If I turn on [custom-http-headers](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md#custom-http-errors) then I get a 404 from nginx; my service is not being hit. According to [re-write logging](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-rewrite-log), the url is being re-written correctly.

I have also hit the service directly from inside the pod, and that works as well.

```
#service.yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: https
    protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app: my-app
  clusterIP: <redacted>
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
```

What could be going wrong?

**EDIT**: Disabling https all over still gives the same 400 error. However, if my app is expecting HTTPS requests, and nginx is sending HTTP requests, then the requests get to the app (but it can't processes them)

Comment: does your service use valid SSL certificate? Nginx will refuse to connect to service having invalid certificate.

Comment: What do you mean valid? The cert is self signed.

Comment: actually I'm not not sure if valid certificate is needed these days (it was needed in older versions). Can you check Nginx logs for 400 errors?

Comment: I see the 400 in the logs, but not where that's coming from (even on -v=5)

Comment: if Nginx is not giving reason for 400 - then 400 is generated not by Nginx. You should examine your app logs.

Comment: The app isn't showing that it even got a request

Comment: also Nginx may silently fail with 400 if there are invalid headers in the request. You can only catch that with tcpdump.

Comment: @VasilyAngapov, that was the error. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: good to hear. Can you tell what header caused the problem?

Comment: It was a host header. Not sure why it was an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx will silently fail with 400 if request headers are invalid (like special characters in it). You can debug that using tcpdump.